# Assinatura Digital de NFE(Nota Fiscal Eletrônica)

Tags: python, nfe, assinatura-digital

Estou desenvolvendo a NFE na linguagem Python, eu já gero o XML, consigo enviar para o Webservice e recebo a resposta, o que preciso agora é a **assinatura digital**

A assinatura é uma tag em xml com alguns valores, segue o modelo

```
 <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" >
     <infNFe Id="NFe31060243816719000108550000000010001234567897"     versao="1.01">
     ...
     </infNFe>
     <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
           <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-  c14n-20010315"/>
           <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
           <Reference URI="#NFe31060243816719000108550000000010001234567897">
           <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped- signature"/>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml- c14n-20010315"/>
           </Transforms>
           <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
              <DigestValue>vFL68WETQ+mvj1aJAMDx+oVi928=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
       </SignedInfo>
     <SignatureValue>IhXNhbdL1F9UGb2ydVc5v/gTB/y6r0KIFaf5evUi1i ...    </SignatureValue>
     <KeyInfo>
        <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>MIIFazCCBFOgAwIBAgIQaHEfNaxSeOEvZGlVDANB ...     </X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</NFe>
```

O que eu sei é que eu preciso gerar os valores para as tags `<DigestValue>`, `<SignatureValue>` e `<X509Certificate>`.

Eu já consigo ler o certificado digital **A1** através do arquivo `.pfx`
Eu já consigo extrair as informações:

- Nome do proprietário do certificado
- Data de início e fim de validade do certificado
- Private Key
- Certificate Key

  De acordo com o [Manual de integração da NFe](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=zxlLdxB/oYA=), diz o seguinte para o preenchimento desses campos. Página 17 e 18

> A assinatura do Contribuinte na NF-e será feita na TAG  identificada pelo atributo
>   Id, cujo conteúdo deverá ser um identificador único (chave de acesso) precedido do literal
>   ‘NFe’ para cada NF-e conforme leiaute descrito no Anexo I. O identificador único precedido
>   do literal ‘#NFe’ deverá ser informado no atributo URI da TAG . Para as demais mensagens a serem assinadas, o processo é o mesmo mantendo sempre um identificador
>   único para o atributo Id na TAG a ser assinada. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

Pelo o que entendi, na chave `NFe31060243816719000108550000000010001234567897`(nesse caso)  ta Tag `<Reference URI="#NFe31060243816719000108550000000010001234567897">`

Para a tag `<DigestValue>` ele diz que tem que ser um algorítimo `SH-1 base 64`, OK isso eu já consigo, mas não fala baseado em quê eu preciso gerar essa chave

O que eu quero saber é, como é gerado de fato esses valores dos campos?

```
<DigestValue>
<SignatureValue>
<X509Certificate>
```

Comment: Você seguiu os links logo abaixo? Se eu tivesse mais experiência com isso, responderia, mas só posso dar o seguinte comentário: 1) O `DigestValue` é um hash daquilo que está sendo assinado (provavelmente um simples SHA-1 do mesmo codificado em base64); 2) O `X509Certificate` é a identificação do certificado usado pra assinar (aquele cuja chave privada você controla, pelo jeito esse mesmo que você leu); 3) O `SignatureValue` é a assinatura do `DigestValue` com a chave privada do certificado, segundo os algoritmos especificados (assinatura e transformações).

Comment: Isso não deve ter ajudado muita coisa, imagino, mas minha sugestão é tentar encontrar alguma biblioteca pra Python que faça assinatura de XML (pois isso é um padrão internacional, o que a NFe usa). De novo, não tenho experiência, mas uma busca rápida me trouxe [esse](https://signxml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), [esse](http://www.decalage.info/python/pyxmldsig) e [esse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmldsig).

Comment: Muito boa suas dicas, o problema é que essas bibliotecas usam o `xmlsec` e ele não funciona de jeito nenhum no Python 3.4, já tentei de tudo, pode funcionar mas não conseguir até agora, teria que ser em Python 3.

A sua primeira resposta é bem por ai mesmo, eu já calculo o `DigestValue` usando o SHA-1 porém nunca é o mesmo que tem esses exemplos. em relação ao `SignatureValue` qual o tipo de algorítimo?

Comment: Se o *digest* está dando errado, talvez você não esteja fazendo o hash dos dados certos. Por exemplo, [aqui](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/xmldsig.html) diz que o elemento a ser hasheado é o `Object`, e no seu texto todos os `\r\n` do texto têm de ser substituídos por um único `\n`, você está fazendo isso? Talvez tenham outros detalhes também, não sei... Quanto ao `SignatureValue`, o tipo de algoritmo está descrito em `SignatureMethod`: RSA-SHA-1. E tem também o `CanonicalizationMethod` que não sei bem pra que serve, além dos `Transforms`. Se tivesse que fazer isso à mão, eu ficaria perdido rsrs.

Comment: quanto aos links, eu entrei nos links mas não entendi, não vi como eu posso gerar esses valores, é um documento MUITO grande rsrsrs. é, acho que essa parte vou ver se faço um script com Python2 só para assinar, é o jeito. rsrs

Comment: Se eu fizer o bendito xmlsec funcionar, ai resolve a questão

Comment: Creio que você esteja fazendo tudo no braço. Se sim, acho que você poderia dar uma olhada nessa [lib](https://github.com/leotada/PyNFe), projeto de biblioteca para fazer interface com o webservice de Nota Fiscal eletrônica para Python, que já vai te dar possibilidades de fazer muitas coisas de uma maneira bem mais simples.

Answer (score 2):

Para calcular o DigestValue

1  acrescentar o namespace xmlns com o valor http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe na tag infNFe

2  canonizar a tag infNFe

3  calcular o Digest usando SHA1 e converter o resultado pra Base64

Para assinar a nota

1  acrescentar o namespace xmlns com o valor http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig# na tag SignedInfo

2  canonizar a tag SignedInfo

3  Assinar a tag SignedInfo, converter o resultado pra Base64

Faltou alguma coisa?

mais detalhes sobre a assinatura https://dev.thiago.pro/assinatura-digital-nfe