# Python + NFSe Prefeitura de BH

Tags: python, python-3.x, nfe

estou tentando integrar meu sistema em Python com a PBH na questao da NFSe. O layout do arquivo esta correto, no entanto, nao consigo assinar o XML.

O layout e este aqui :

```
    <Signature Id="Ass_rps:ABCDZ">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference URI="#rps:1ABCDZ">
               <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                 </Transforms>
                 <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                 <DigestValue> </DigestValue>
           </Reference>
           </SignedInfo>
                 <SignatureValue> </SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                 <X509Data>
                   <X509Certificate> </X509Certificate>
                 </X509Data>
             </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
```

Antes desta parte na nota vem as tags com valores, descricao dos servicos, etc. Estou precisando muito de ajuda para gerar o DigestValue,SignatureValue e o X509Certificate em python. 
Alguem pode me ajudar?

Muito obrigado,

Comment: Você tem um link pra uma referência, uma documentação, algo assim? Em linhas gerais, o `DigestValue` é o SHA1 de alguma coisa, o `X509Certificate` é um certificado em formato padrão usando o algorimo RSA (acho), e o `SignatureValue` é a assinatura do `DigestValue` usando o certificado e o algoritmo RSA-SHA1. Esse é um método bastante padronizado, se procurar aqui mesmo no SOpt encontrará perguntas similares para outras linguagens. Mas para adaptar isso pra Python, alguns detalhes extra são necessários, daí a importância de um link pra documentação.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: ["Assinatura Digital de NFE(Nota Fiscal Eletrônica)"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89735/215)

Comment: Infelizmente nao. Tenho exemplos de codigos que sao para NFE e nao estao tao bem documentados como o : https://github.com/aricaldeira/PySPED/tree/master/pysped
Se eu ao menos conseguisse retirar a parte so da assinatura, resolvia. Ja enviei email pro autor, mas ele nao respondeu...

Comment: então  primeiro passo é achar a documentação - esse tipo de coisa não dá pra fazer no "achômetro".

Comment: A documentacao do layout xml esta em http://www.pbh.gov.br/bhissdigital/download/nfse/Manual_De_Integracao_WebService_NFS-e_Belo_Horizonte.pdf, mas nao diz muito.